# How to expose an websocket endpoint in kubernetes (EKS) for a spring application

Tags: websocket, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have deployed a spring application with a domain lets say bala.something.com , now the developer has made some changes and wanted to expose the websocket endpoint.

websocat wss://bala.something.com/api/ws should connect.

the application is running as a pod in AWS EKS and the requests goes through the elastic load balancer with nginx as ingress controller.

I have no idea on how to expose the websocket , can someone shed some light on this and possible options to explore ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hello @Balakrishna You can look at the example of [websocket support](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/websocket#websocket-support) for NGINX Ingress controller

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin , thanks for the comment, I tried the same way which is mentioned in the github link above still getting 400 bad request

Comment: Did you change name of the service in annotation of your Ingress resource?
`nginx.org/websocket-services: "nameof-your-service"` In example the name in annotation is only for websocket service: "ws-svc"

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin Yeah I changed the name, The websocket request is reaching my service but getting the following error from logs
"Handshake failed due to invalid upgrade header: null"

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin , I am running the below command to test the websocket connection : "websocat wss://bala.something.com/api/ws

Comment: Can you add a description for your Ingress resource?